# Multiple skew rectangle

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I'm trying to make something like that with CSS

[image]

Should it be possible?

This is what I got nearly

```css
a {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 18%;
  background: #00aeef;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
}

a::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #00aeef;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  -ms-transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Teste</a>
```

So how can I make multiple skew like the layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With few minor updates to your own code using `border` and `box-shadow`, i was able to achieve the expected result, please have a look at the below working snippet :)

```css
a {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0px 50px 0px 18%;
  background: #00aeef;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
}

a:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #00aeef;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  -ms-transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
  border-left: 5px solid white;
  border-right: 5px solid white;
  box-shadow: 5px 0 0 0 #00aeef;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Teste</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the background-color with a gradient within your pseudo-element;

```css
a {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 18%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background:#00aeef;
  position: relative;
}

a::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: 
  linear-gradient(to right, #00aeef 10px,
        transparent 11px,transparent 15px,
        #00aeef 16px,#00aeef 30px,
        transparent 31px,transparent 35px,
        #00aeef 36px,#00aeef 40px
        );
  transform-origin:top left;
  transform: skewX(-30deg)
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Teste</a>
```

You can also do it with **one** element considering multiple background and no need for pseudo-element and transform:

```css
a {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0px 60px 0px 18%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: 
  linear-gradient(#00aeef,#00aeef) left/calc(100% - 40px) 100% no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(115deg, #00aeef 10px,
        transparent 11px,transparent 15px,
        #00aeef 16px,#00aeef 25px,
        transparent 26px,transparent 30px,
        #00aeef 31px,#00aeef 35px,
        transparent 35px, transparent 100%) right/40px 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Teste</a>
```